# Displaying non-existing(in database table) column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a table 'Employee' with name, surname, dateOfBirth and so one.

This table doesn't contain `Age` column, but I need to compute and display age in DataGridView with Name.

Like this:

```
John  30 

Mary  25
```

The problem is when I execute query

```
select FirstName, DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) as Age from Empoyee
```

in SQL Server, I get what I need, but when I try to fill DataGridView the `Age` column is displayed incorrect.

```
edDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
edDataGridView.DataSource = context.Empoyee.SqlQuery("SELECT FirstName, DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) as Age from Empoyee").ToList();
```

Please tell me how to do this right. May be I should use LINQ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is being displayed and what you think it should be please?

Comment: I understood, that incorrect displaying was because of AutoGeneratingColumns, then i set it false and nothing has been displayed. So I think I need to add some columns in DataGridView, but how can I bind Age column?

Comment: Something is showing up in your DataGridView - you say it is being "displayed incorrect" -- but what is being displayed?  How is it incorrect?

Comment: Have you created a DataGridViewColumn and set DataPropertyName?
Did you Add DataGridViewColumn to DataGRidView?

Comment: @ХарламовДаниил You said it worked when you set `AutoGeneratingColumns = true`. Unless there is a reason to set it to `false`, leave it at `true` and everything is fine. No issues, no problems

Comment: When the AutoGeneratingColumns property was true, some column was added from the right side of the table. When I executed that query in SQL Server studio the Age column has been added from the right, too, so that's why I said 'incorrect'. But actually, Age column didn't appear.

Comment: About binding: I know how to bind DataGridView columns with database columns, but is it possible to bind a column which does not exist in database?

Comment: I tried, didn't work, Age column is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself, thank all))

```
        edDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        var query = from e in context.Empoyee
                    select new
                    {
                        e.FirstName, Age = DateTime.Now.Year - e.DateOfBirth.Year
                    };

        edDataGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
```